# CST 0001 ERRO [comm.tls] ClientHandshake -> Client TLS handshake failed after 173.725µs with error EOF remoteaddress=127.0.0.1:7051

Tags: ssl, hyperledger, fabric, handshake

fabric: v2.5.4
docker: v24.0.5
docker-compose: v1.25.0
When running `./test-network.sh createChannel`, the error occurs.

```
Channel 'mychannel' created
Joining org1 peer to the channel...
Using organization 1
+ peer channel join -b ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block
+ res=1
+ peer channel join -b ./channel-artifacts/mychannel.block
+ res=0
2024-03-28 16:27:18.121 CST 0001 ERRO [comm.tls] ClientHandshake -> Client TLS handshake failed after 173.725µs with error: EOF remoteaddress=127.0.0.1:7051
2024-03-28 16:27:19.127 CST 0002 INFO [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> Endorser and orderer connections initialized
2024-03-28 16:27:24.065 CST 0003 INFO [channelCmd] executeJoin -> Successfully submitted proposal to join channel
```

I'm trying to configure a four-node network. Could someone tell me how to solve this problem? it may associate with the ports' setting.